# How to build parse tree with BNF

Tags: python, parsing

I need to build parse tree for some source code (on Python or any program language that describe by CFG).

So, I have source code on some programming language and BNF this language.

Can anybody give some advice how can I build parse tree in this case?
Preferably, with tools for Python.

Comment: This question is very difficult to understand. Can you please consider rewriting it with a better description of what you are looking for and what you have already tried.

Comment: Not a data science question, its a programming question. Go ask on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), which is a very powerful parser generator. It has a good GUI for entering your BNF. It has a [Python target](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Python+Target) capability.